# react css file linking problem with app.js

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I am a beginner to React and currently I am doing my first program in React by watching YouTube tutorial, but I can't add the CSS page in my `app.js`. It does not display the file name when I type in.

This is mine:

[image: this is mine]

This is the YouTube instructor's:

[image: this the image of the youtube instructor]

Comment: Kindly provide minimal, reproducible code to see the problem exactly. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for better understanding. Edit the question to include the code of `userProfile.jsx`. Note include it as a code not as an image.

Comment: If you could share what is in the css file, that would be useful. Do you have a styled classname called "App"?